# Custom `polars` expression involving multiple columns and filtering

Tags: python, python-polars

Consider the following function acting on a `polars.DataFrame`

```py
import polars as pl


def f(frame: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    """Select columns 'A', 'B' form `frame` and return only those rows for which col. 'C' is greater than 7."""
    return frame.filter(pl.col("C") > 7.0).select("A", "B")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    frame = pl.from_dict({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6], "C": [7, 8, 9]})
    result = frame.pipe(f)
    print(result)
    >>> shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ 5   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

In order to abstract away from specific column names I can write this as

```py
import polars as pl


def g(a: pl.Series, b: pl.Series, c: pl.Series) -> pl.DataFrame:
    frame = pl.concat([a.to_frame(), b.to_frame(), c.to_frame()], how="horizontal")
    return frame.filter(pl.col("C") > 7.0).select("A", "B")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    frame = pl.from_dict({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6], "C": [7, 8, 9]})
    result = g(frame.get_column("A"), frame.get_column("B"), frame.get_column("C"))    
    print(result)
>>> shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ 5   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

This somehow seems cumbersome as it involves extracting `pl.Series` from `pl.DataFrame` followed by `pl.concat` and multiple recasts to `pl.DataFrame`.

Would it be possible to write this as a custom expression instead? I'd like to apply it as outlined below

```py
import polars as pl


def h(a: pl.Expr, b: pl.Expr, c: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    # How to represent f (or g) in terms of only `pl.Expr`?
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    frame = pl.from_dict({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6], "C": [7, 8, 9]})
    result = frame.select(h(pl.col("A"), pl.col("B"), pl.col("C")))
    print(result)
>>> shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ 5   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

I am not sure if that is the intended usage of the `pl.Expr` type. It seems to be a nice way to not rely on specific column names (although implicitly requiring that those expressions evaluate to 'series' with identical length and appropriate data type for the expression to work).

Comment: The last example is just `return a, b, c` or `def h(*exprs): return exprs` so I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious here. Is the last example also supposed to pass the filter expression to the function? You're passing `C` in the examples 2/3, yet, the output only contains `A` and `B` - is this intended?

Comment: Sorry for the too long line in function `g`, I edited the example. I am passing `C` just for filtering, I only need the values of `A` and `B` conditional on the values of `C`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh right, like `return a.filter(c), b.filter(c)`?

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! I'd like to accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're passing the result to `DataFrame.select()` - you can use [`Expr.filter()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.filter.html) to build the expressions.

```py
def my_func(a, b, c): 
    return a.filter(c), b.filter(c)

df = pl.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6], "C": [7, 8, 9]})

df.select(my_func(pl.col("A"), pl.col("B"), pl.col("C") > 7))
```

```py
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ 5   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┘
```